# how make of js code for every append() div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var p=$('.Tex_1st_con_mes p');
  while ($(p).outerHeight()>80) {
   $(p).text(function (index, text) {
      return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
   });
  }

$(document).on('click','button',function(){
  $('body').append('<div class="Tex_1st_con_mes"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p></div>')
});
```

```css
.Tex_1st_con_mes
{
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    left:2px;
    max-width:390px;
    font-family:Arial;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    overflow-wrap:break-word;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:20px;
    max-height:80px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.Tex_1st_con_mes p
{
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
}
button
{
    position:absolute;
    left:420px;
    top:15px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Tex_1st_con_mes">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the            1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to          make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but            also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially                  unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset            sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
</div>
<button>Add new text</button>
```

Hello,
When `.Tex_1st_con_mes p` is greater than `80px` text is hidden and show '...', but when I append the same class it's no working.

My question: how make that if I append this code '...' will show. I thing I should use `$(this)` but I don't know how

Comment: not clear at all. . explain more

Comment: if I add text in html between <p> and this <p> is greater than 80px text is cut and insert '...' at the end, but this works only for first, when I append new divs (click in button) my js code not working

Comment: Does your regex `\W*\s(\S)*$` should match first sentence?

Comment: yes, should match first sentence

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that you only do your replacement on page load and do not execute it once added new text.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  toggleHeight();

  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('body').append($('#template').html());
    toggleHeight();
  });
})

function toggleHeight() {
  $('.Tex_1st_con_mes.new').removeClass('new').find('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > 80) {
      var newContent = $(this).text();
      newContent = newContent.substring(newContent.indexOf('.') + 2)+'...';
      $(this).text(newContent);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.Tex_1st_con_mes {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 2px;
  max-width: 390px;
  font-family: Arial;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  max-height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.Tex_1st_con_mes p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 420px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Tex_1st_con_mes new"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p></div>
<button>Add new text</button>

<script type="text/template" id="template">
<div class="Tex_1st_con_mes new"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p></div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call below code every time at completion of append.

```
var p=$('.Tex_1st_con_mes p');
  while ($(p).outerHeight()>80) {
   $(p).text(function (index, text) {
      return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
   });
  }
```

I suggest to make a function of this code and then call that function after every successful append.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `each` to loop through the elements, check for `outerHeight` and change the text:

```
$('.Tex_1st_con_mes p').each(function() {
 var $this = $(this);
 if ($this.outerHeight() > 80) {
  $this.text($this.text().replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...'));
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for advise, but I thin this is not working properly